# What does the correspondence spell really tell?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

I've had a mage in my group using correspondence on 2 werewolves (1 was as a mortal the maid of the sister of the other and they knew ech other from childhood as acquaintances).

Now the description of the spell is just confusing.....so what exactly does: Correspondence (Space •)  tell someone?

What we are confused is WHAT you really get out of it. For example one werewolf player wanted to tell what exactly is the history of the two wolves, while the other wanted to tell what is the NATURE of their relation and I and one of the mages read it as "only the strength of a relation is told"

*(either in this example and/or generally as neither I nor my players am really getting the description exactly).

Answer (score 4):

It provides the “degree of sympathetic connection.” In other words, **how closely** they are connected; the **strength** of their connection. It doesn't tell how they're connected or the details and history of the connection, just how closely they are connected — and therefore, how useful their connection would be for casting a Sympathetic Spell.

Comment: A strong connection would beg further investigation, if the Mage happens to have other tools and time at their disposal. Meanwhile a weak connection (or no connection) between two seemingly allied Werewolves might reveal hidden weakness that could be capitalized on. Just because the tool has a perfect use doesn't mean it doesn't have countless side benefits to the creative.